# Can you sort barchart by values in databricks-sql dashboard?

Tags: databricks, dashboard, databricks-sql

Can you sort barchart in databricks sql dashboard?
( https://docs.databricks.com/sql/user/dashboards/index.html )
I'm trying to create a barchart with in databricks-dashboard-sql tool and sort it by its value (not alphabetically by its category).
On preview, it looks like this (sorted by its value in descending order, which is how it is supposed to be):
[image]

But when I choose save visualization and add it to the dashboard then it is automatically unsorted. Any idea about how to properly fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option you can try is to disable aggregations in the chart definition:

[image]